# How to authenticate with dotnet core and windows auth

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have successfully called challenge and got auto-login working. However, if the app is hosted on a different domain than the one the user is on, it will not work. Instead of challenging and getting a windows dialog pop-up, i want to be able to provide the user with a nice UX and give a screen for logging in.

I have done this, but i can't find how i can actually authenticate the user against windows auth with their provided username and password.

EDIT:
I am using identity server for the bulk of the work so far.

I have found I can do the following:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
bool success = ctx.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password);
```

However I am stuck as to how to now get the subjectid and go through the normal net core workflow to issue auth cookie etc. Normally i would do:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);
```